# SQL filter rows in table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to select rows from a table with the exception of any rows containing 'NEW_' at the beginning. I think I have the logic correct but I am unsure of the syntax. Can anyone help me out?

```
 SELECT * 
FROM CUSTOMER e1
WHERE e1.cust_ref LIKE 'CUST_REF%'
  AND e1.cust_ref NOT IN (SELECT e2.cust_ref 
                       FROM CUSTOMER e2  
                       WHERE e1.cust_ref = 'NEW_' + e2.cust_ref);
```

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: Please add sample data and desired results.  Your problem statement is clear enough, but why does your query have two tables?

Comment: Sorry made mistake. Updated code to closer replicate what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from CUSTOMER 
WHERE cust_ref  like 'CUST_REF%'
AND cust_ref not in 
(select cust_ref from sd_filter_element where cust_ref not like 'NEW_%');
```

You should use `like` to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is SQL query for filter option

```
select * 
from sd_filter_element
WHERE 
cust_ref not like 'NEW_%';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want cust refs that don't have "NEW_", why not just do this?

```
select c.*
from CUSTOMER c
WHERE c.cust_ref not like 'NEW_%' ;
```